# Problems with accents and special characters using xelatex template for CV

Tags: xetex, accents

I am building my CV using [this xeLaTeX template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/wilson-resume-cv).

When trying to include accents as I usually do in LaTeX, I got wrong symbols like this:

[image: wrong symbol]

Looking at the template code, it includes the following:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{fontspec} % Required for specification of custom fonts

\setmainfont[Path = ./fonts/,
Extension = .otf,
BoldFont = Erewhon-Bold,
ItalicFont = Erewhon-Italic, 
BoldItalicFont = Erewhon-BoldItalic,
SmallCapsFeatures = {Letters = SmallCaps}
]{Erewhon-Regular}
```

I also tried to use babel,

```
\usepackage[spanish, american]{babel}
```

switching back and forth between American and Spanish with `\selectlanguage` command. No success.

Any ideas about how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't load `inputenc` along with `fontspec`

Comment: Note also that the "preferred" way of using the `\set*font` commands from `fontspec` is now: `\setmainfont{<fontname>}[<options>]`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't load `inputenc` nor `fontenc` (this one might be needed in special occasions, though) when you compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and use `fontspec`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,american]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{erewhon}

\begin{document}

This is American English: Alcalá de Henares

\selectlanguage{spanish}

Esto es español: Alcalá de Henares

\end{document}
```

The declaration `\setmainfont{erewhon}` might need to be more detailed, depending on whether you installed the font in your system or not. In case it is not installed as a system font, then your declarations are good, but probably it's better to use shortcuts:

```
\setmainfont[
  Path            = ./fonts/,
  Extension       = .otf,
  UprightFont     = *-Regular,
  BoldFont        = *-Bold,
  ItalicFont      = *-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont  = *-BoldItalic,
]{Erewhon}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @egreg, but still doesn't work... The fonts are not installed in my system, but rather copied in the ./fonts subdirectory

Comment: @cecadepeca I removed `fontenc` and `inputenc` from `structure.tex` and changed the call of `\setmainfont` as suggested; did you try removing `Path=./.fonts/`? It shouldn't be necessary if you have an up-to-date TeX Live.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but my MikTeX installation is a bit out-of-date, and honestly, I don't have time to update it now. I might try to install the font on my system if necessary, if I found some simple instructions. I have a very bad experience installing LaTeX fonts... :(

Comment: @cecadepeca Install Erewhon as a system font.

Comment: Thanks @egreg. Erewhon font installed correctly. Now I can get rid of the `Path=./.fonts/`line safely. `fontenc` and `inputenc` also removed from `structure.tex` But still got the same problem with the accents.... really strange

Comment: Are you sure your .tex file is utf8-encoded?